# displaying transition doesn't work on css and react.js

Tags: css, reactjs, hover, css-transitions, display

```
.cartBtn {
  appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: inherit;
}
.cartBtn:hover {
  color: black;
}

.cart {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 4s ease-in-out;
}

.cart-toggle:hover .cart {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}

.cart-toggle {
  position: relative;
}
```

```
    <button className={styled.cartBtn}>
          <h3>Cart</h3>
          <div className={styled.cart}>
            <Cart />
          </div>
        </button>
      </div>
```

I have a button in my nav and when I hover it I want this cart to show. The cart is a box that contains some items and is written as position absolute. Between text and the box that toggle there is a space and when I try to hover over the box, I can't even reach it. So if I can put a transition I can reach but the problem is my transition doesn't work.

Comment: transition does not work for the `display` property

Comment: how can i make it work ? other than display

Comment: you can use visibility and height

Answer (score 0):

there is no animation of display. I handle the problem by setting timeout, but there are specific packages just for these, like CSSTransition. This is link of CSSTransition doc: https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/css-transition

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).